# Add custom file type to quarkusDev watchlist for live reload

Tags: quarkus

I have a gradle project with a custom source directory set containing text files that are used by a code generator to generate java code. I have a gradle plugin that wires all of this together.

I'm wondering how I can have quarkus dev mode do a live reload when my text files change. Provided quarkus dev runs a compile, everything should update correctly.

I'm not sure where to even start.

Comment: Do you have a custom Quarkus extension as well?

Answer (score 0):

It may be slight overkill for this situation, but by coincidence, I've just done something similar.

I started with a [Quarkus extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension)

```
mvn io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.6.5:create-extension -N \
    -DgroupId=org.acme \ 
    -DextensionId=codegen-extension \  
    -DwithoutTests
```

That extension needs to include a class which implements `io.quarkus.deployment.dev.CompilationProvider`. It will call out to the code which converts the text files into `.class` files. If your generator just converts the text files to `.java` files, you might need a second step which calls a Java compiler.

For example:

```
public class MyCustomCompilationProvider implements CompilationProvider {

    @Override
    public Set<String> handledExtensions() {
        return Collections.singleton(".myextension");
    }

    @Override
    public String getProviderKey() {
        return "some-key";
    }

    @Override
    public void compile(Set<File> files, Context context) {

        // Ensure the directory we're going to write into exists
        context.getOutputDirectory()
               .mkdirs();

        final var codeGenerator = new MyCustomCompiler();

        for (var file : files) {
            final var outFile = new File(context.getOutputDirectory()
                                                .getPath(),
                    FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName()) + DOT_CLASS);

            try {
                compiler.compile(new FileInputStream(file), outFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll also need to register the provider in your extension's deployment module, using the META-INF-services mechanism. You should create a file in `<your-extension>/deployment/src/main/resources/META-INF/services` which contains the fully qualified class name of your compilation provider:

[image: a registered compilation provider]

Comment: thanks for the response! I was wondering if an extension would be required. I was really hoping to avoid that. I'll explore that avenue then.

Comment: I know what you mean! An extension feels heavy compared to a little config flag or something, but it's actually not that much code beyond what the scaffolding.